# find and replace pattern with relation symbols and numbers

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am working on a tex file where I want to convert a pattern as such:

```
lorem ipsum > 3 dolor sit amet
lorem ipsum < 0.45 dolor sit amet
lorem ipsum == 1 dolor sit amet
```

into:

```
lorem ipsum $> 3$ dolor sit amet
lorem ipsum $< 0.45$ dolor sit amet
lorem ipsum $== 1$ dolor sit amet
```

Basically, I want to encase the symbol and the number following it with $.

I'm thinking of sed or regex solution, but I'm a beginner on those. Would appreciate a solution and some elaboration if that's not too much.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the rules for inserting the `$` signs? There are many ways to get the result you've shown but only a few of them are likely correct. Example: `sed -E 's/(\S+\s+\S+)$/$\1$/'`

Comment: Basic idea would be `([<>=]+ [\d\.]+)` replaced with `$\1\$`.

Comment: Does that work: `sed -E 's/ ([0-9.><= ]+ ) / $\1$ /g'` ?

Comment: `sed 's/\([<>=]\{1,\}[[:space:]][[:digit:].]\{1,\}\)/\$\1\$/' file.txt `

Comment: Thanks all! Jetchisel's solution works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -E 's/([<>=]+\s+[0-9.]+)/$\1$/'
```

- `( ... )` captures what you match on
- `[<>=]` matches any of the characters `<`, `>` and `=`
- `+` means match 1-many of the previous expression
- `\s` matches whitespace (a GNU exension - use `[[:space:]]` if `\s` isn't available)
- `[0-9.]` matches digits and `.`
- `$\1$` replaces what you captured with the same thing (`\1` - the first capture) but with `$` on both sides.